# Is there a way to know if an image has been loaded in the dom on Angular

Tags: angular, typescript, viewchild, angular-lifecycle-hooks

I'm actually working on Angular and I want to know if there is a way to know if an image has been loaded correctly in the dom. I trie using `this.image.nativeElement.width` but the width is sent before the image loading.

HTML

```
<img #image [src]="imagePath">
```

TS

```
@ViewChild('image', {static: true})
  image: ElementRef<HTMLImageElement>;
```

Comment: What do you mean correctly? I believe the image would load normally if you gave it the correct `src`.

Comment: AFAIK `img` tag has `onLoad()` and `onError()` handles. Use them.

Comment: Thanks @Rafael but the onLoad method is called even if the image is not loaded correctly

Comment: @manjirosano the src is a link, so there is some latency between the moment I get the width and when the image is loaded. Is there any workaround to handle this lazy loading. I want to get the width of the image only when It's loaded to avoid getting 0

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can do it in two ways:

**Using AfterViewInit and access the element**

```
@ViewChild('image')
  public img: ElementRef;

  ngAfterViewInit() {
    const image: HTMLImageElement = this.img.nativeElement;

    image.onload = () => {
      console.log('image loaded');
    };
  }
```

**Using (load) event**

```
<img #image [src]="imagePath" (load)="functionAfterLoad()">
```

https://stackblitz.com/edit/rotate-image-bdqndf?file=app/app.component.ts

Comment: ngAfterContentInit is always infinitely called

Comment: Using (load) results in the same issue. When I try to access to the viewChild, the element is undefined

Comment: I have updated the code please check it out. Added stackblitz as well.